# Ionic 2 Leitura json

Tags: json, typescript, ionic2

Pessoal Estou tentando ler um json no ionic, criei o service da seguinte maneira :
http://pastebin.com/0btbuC83
minha classe esta assim :
http://pastebin.com/6gdpBth4
e meu json é assim :
http://pastebin.com/gVSVCsQN
Porem o meu alert da classe só retorna undefined... Como posso arrumar ?
Obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O código `alert(data.id);` não irá exibir nada mesmo. Afinal data é um vetor.
Para acessar o atributo id, será necessário especificar a posição do vetor ou utilizar um laço (for, foreach, etc).

Exemplo:

```
alert(data[0].id);
```

Comment: Diego, nesse caso, coloque as flags informando que a pergunta está incompleta! Obs: Do meu ponto de vista, isso ainda sim responde a pergunta. Afinal estou mostrando o problema com o código dele.

Comment: Diego: "Porem o meu alert da classe só retorna undefined... Como posso arrumar ?". Minha resposta responde isso perfeitamente para os detalhes que foram providos.

Answer (score -1):

Para aparecer no alert o seu resultado é necessario utilizar um metodo de conversao do objeto para string.
ex: JSON.stringify(data);